# Show progress bar for different states

Tags: javascript, css, comparative-review, vue.js

I have this working code which shows the progress bar based on different states ("not-started", "progressing" and "done"). Each state will have its own class.

I notice it is not Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) enough but not sure how I can refactor it. Appreciate your code review.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#page",
  data: {
    currentStepNumber:10,
    totalEformStepNumber: 9,
    totalVerificationStepNumber: 2,
    totalReviewStepNumber: 1,
    eFormProgress: "not-started",
    verificationProgress: "not-started",
    reviewProgress: "not-started",
    verificationDone: false,
    encourageText: "Let's Start"
  },
  computed: {
    checkEFormProgress() {
      if (this.eFormProgress === "not-started") {
        return "step-indicator-not-started";
      } else if (this.eFormProgress === "progressing") {
        return "step-indicator-progressing";
      } else if (this.eFormProgress === "done") {
        return "step-indicator-done";
      }
    },
    checkVerificationProgress() {
      if (this.verificationProgress === "not-started") {
        return "step-indicator-not-started";
      } else if (this.verificationProgress === "progressing") {
        return "step-indicator-progressing";
      } else if (this.verificationProgress === "done") {
        return "step-indicator-done";
      }
    },
    checkReviewProgress() {
      if (this.reviewProgress === "not-started") {
        return "step-indicator-not-started";
      } else if (this.reviewProgress === "progressing") {
        return "step-indicator-progressing";
      } else if (this.reviewProgress === "done") {
        return "step-indicator-done";
      }
    },
    totalStepNumber() {
      return (
        this.totalEformStepNumber +
        this.totalVerificationStepNumber +
        this.totalReviewStepNumber
      );
    },
    eformCurrentStepNumber() {
      if (this.currentStepNumber === 0) {
        this.eFormProgress = "not-started";
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = "progressing";
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = "done";
      }
      return (this.currentStepNumber / this.totalEformStepNumber) * 100;
    },
    verifcationCurrentStepNumber() {
      debugger;
      if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = "not-started";
        } else if (this.currentStepNumber > this.totalEformStepNumber && this.currentStepNumber < this.totalStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = "progressing";
        } else if (this.currentStepNumber === this.totalStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = "done";          
          this.reviewProgress = "done";
        }
        return (
          ((this.currentStepNumber - this.totalEformStepNumber) /
            this.totalVerificationStepNumber) *
          100
        );
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    },
    eformProgressWidth() {
      return this.eformCurrentStepNumber > 100
        ? { width: "100%" }
        : { width: this.eformCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
    },
    verificationProgressWidth() {
      return this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber >= 100
        ? { width: "100%" }
        : { width: this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  created() {}
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
 p {
     margin: 0;
}
 #page {
     font-family: Roboto;
     width: 100%;
     background: #f8f9fa;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}
 .container {
     width: 70%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .progress-bar {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: flex-start;
     width: 100%;
}
 .point {
     width: 38px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     gap: 8px;
     color: #28a745;
}
 .step-indicator-not-started {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #ecedee;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: none;
}
 .step-indicator-progressing {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #ecedee;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .step-indicator-done {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #28a745;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .bar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 16px;
     display: grid;
     align-items: center;
}
 .bar-eform {
     width: 80%;
}
 .bar-verification {
     width: 20%;
}
 .bar-bg {
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #ecedee;
     position: relative;
}
 .bar-arrow {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #28a745;
}
 .page-indicator {
     color: #28a745;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{{encourageText}}</h3>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkEFormProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>EForm</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-eform">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="eformProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkVerificationProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Verification</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-verification">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="verificationProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkReviewProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Review</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-indicator">
    <strong>{{currentStepNumber}}/{{totalStepNumber}}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Version 2, I have done some refactoring as below.

```js
const stateProgress = {
  NOTSTARTED: "not-started",
  PROGRESSING: "progressing",
  DONE: "done"
};

const stateProgressClassName = {
  NOTSTARTED: "step-indicator-not-started",
  PROGRESSING: "step-indicator-progressing",
  DONE: "step-indicator-done"
};

new Vue({
  el: "#page",
  data: {
    currentStepNumber: 2,
    totalEformStepNumber: 9,
    totalVerificationStepNumber: 2,
    totalReviewStepNumber: 1,
    eFormProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    verificationProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    reviewProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    encourageText: "Let's Start"
  },
  computed: {
    checkEFormProgress() {
      return this.getProgressClassName(this.eFormProgress);      
    },
    checkVerificationProgress() {
      return this.getProgressClassName(this.verificationProgress);
    },
    checkReviewProgress() {
      return this.getProgressClassName(this.reviewProgress);
    },
    totalStepNumber() {
      return (
        this.totalEformStepNumber +
        this.totalVerificationStepNumber +
        this.totalReviewStepNumber
      );
    },
    eformCurrentStepNumber() {
      if (this.currentStepNumber <= 0) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.NOTSTARTED;
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.DONE;
      }
      return (this.currentStepNumber / this.totalEformStepNumber) * 100;
    },
    verifcationCurrentStepNumber() {
      debugger;
      if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.NOTSTARTED;
        } else if (
          this.currentStepNumber > this.totalEformStepNumber &&
          this.currentStepNumber < this.totalStepNumber
        ) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
        } else if (this.currentStepNumber === this.totalStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.DONE;
          this.reviewProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
        }
        return (
          ((this.currentStepNumber - this.totalEformStepNumber) /
            this.totalVerificationStepNumber) *
          100
        );
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    },
    eformProgressWidth() {
      return this.eformCurrentStepNumber > 100
        ? { width: "100%" }
        : { width: this.eformCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
    },
    verificationProgressWidth() {
      return this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber >= 100
        ? { width: "100%" }
        : { width: this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getProgressClassName : function(progressState) {
      if (progressState === stateProgress.NOTSTARTED) {
        return stateProgressClassName.NOTSTARTED;
      } else if (progressState === stateProgress.PROGRESSING) {
        return stateProgressClassName.PROGRESSING;
      } else if (progressState === stateProgress.DONE) {
        return stateProgressClassName.DONE;
      }      
    }
  },
  created() {}
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
 p {
     margin: 0;
}
 #page {
     font-family: Roboto;
     width: 100%;
     background: #f8f9fa;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}
 .container {
     width: 70%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .progress-bar {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: flex-start;
     width: 100%;
}
 .point {
     width: 38px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     gap: 8px;
     color: #28a745;
}
 .step-indicator-not-started {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #ecedee;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: none;
}
 .step-indicator-progressing {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #ecedee;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .step-indicator-done {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     background: #28a745;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .bar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 16px;
     display: grid;
     align-items: center;
}
 .bar-eform {
     width: 80%;
}
 .bar-verification {
     width: 20%;
}
 .bar-bg {
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #ecedee;
     position: relative;
}
 .bar-arrow {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #28a745;
}
 .page-indicator {
     color: #28a745;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{{encourageText}}</h3>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkEFormProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Account</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-eform">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="eformProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkVerificationProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Verification</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-verification">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="verificationProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="checkReviewProgress">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Review</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-indicator">
    <strong>{{currentStepNumber}}/{{totalStepNumber}}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the second version pulls the states out into an enum-like object. This does make it simpler to work with in the methods for the computed properties. Bear in mind that while `stateProgress` and `stateProgressClassName` are declared with `const` so they cannot be re-assigned, it is possible to assign properties on them. If that should be prevented then use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

The method `getProgressClassName()` could just verify that the value in `progressState` exists in `stateProgress` (using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)) and if so, return `"step-indicator-" + stateProgress`. However, it appears that those calls names are redundant also. Let's look at the styles for those classes:

> ```
>  .step-indicator-not-started {
>      width: 15px;
>      height: 15px;
>      border-radius: 100px;
>      background: #ecedee;
>      box-sizing: border-box;
>      border: none;
> }
>  .step-indicator-progressing {
>      width: 15px;
>      height: 15px;
>      border-radius: 100px;
>      background: #ecedee;
>      box-sizing: border-box;
>      border: 4px solid #28a745;
> }
>  .step-indicator-done {
>      width: 15px;
>      height: 15px;
>      border-radius: 100px;
>      background: #28a745;
>      box-sizing: border-box;
>      border: 4px solid #28a745;
> }
> ```

All three of those have four styles in common: width, height, border-radius and box-sizing.

One could abstract those styles into a separate ruleset for a new class `.step-indicator` that has those common styles:

```css
.step-indicator {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .not-started {
     background: #ecedee;
     border: none;
}
 .progressing {
     background: #ecedee;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .done {
     background: #28a745;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
```

In order to use those, the `step-indicator` class can be separated from the three classes, which allows those associated computed properties to be eliminated, along with `stateProgressClassName` and the method `getProgressClassName`.

For instance:

> ```
> <div :class="checkEFormProgress">
> ```

Can be updated to the following [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax):

```
<div :class="[eFormProgress, 'step-indicator']">
```

Also there is some redundancy in those last two computed properties:

> ```
> eformProgressWidth() {
>   return this.eformCurrentStepNumber > 100
>     ? { width: "100%" }
>     : { width: this.eformCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
> },
> verificationProgressWidth() {
>   return this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber >= 100
>     ? { width: "100%" }
>     : { width: this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber + "%" };
> }
> ```

The ternary operators could be moved inside the object:

```
eformProgressWidth() {
  return { 
    width: this.eformCurrentStepNumber > 100
      ? "100%" 
      : this.eformCurrentStepNumber + "%" 
  };
},
verificationProgressWidth() {
  return { 
    width: this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber >= 100 
      ? "100%" 
      : this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber + "%" 
  };
}
```

The [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) function can help simplify these methods to a single line each:

```
    eformProgressWidth() {
      return { width: Math.min(this.eformCurrentStepNumber, 100) + "%" };
    },
    verificationProgressWidth() {
      return { width: Math.min(this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber, 100) + "%" };
    }
```

These suggestions can lead to greatly reduced code.

```js
const stateProgress = {
  NOTSTARTED: "not-started",
  PROGRESSING: "progressing",
  DONE: "done"
};

new Vue({
  el: "#page",
  data: {
    currentStepNumber: 2,
    totalEformStepNumber: 9,
    totalVerificationStepNumber: 2,
    totalReviewStepNumber: 1,
    eFormProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    verificationProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    reviewProgress: stateProgress.NOTSTARTED,
    encourageText: "Let's Start"
  },
  computed: {
    totalStepNumber() {
      return (
        this.totalEformStepNumber +
        this.totalVerificationStepNumber +
        this.totalReviewStepNumber
      );
    },
    eformCurrentStepNumber() {
      if (this.currentStepNumber <= 0) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.NOTSTARTED;
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
      } else if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        this.eFormProgress = stateProgress.DONE;
      }
      return (this.currentStepNumber / this.totalEformStepNumber) * 100;
    },
    verifcationCurrentStepNumber() {
      //debugger;
      if (this.currentStepNumber >= this.totalEformStepNumber) {
        if (this.currentStepNumber < this.totalEformStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.NOTSTARTED;
        } else if (
          this.currentStepNumber > this.totalEformStepNumber &&
          this.currentStepNumber < this.totalStepNumber
        ) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
        } else if (this.currentStepNumber === this.totalStepNumber) {
          this.verificationProgress = stateProgress.DONE;
          this.reviewProgress = stateProgress.PROGRESSING;
        }
        return (
          ((this.currentStepNumber - this.totalEformStepNumber) /
            this.totalVerificationStepNumber) *
          100
        );
      } 
      return 0;
    },
    eformProgressWidth() {
      return { width: Math.min(this.eformCurrentStepNumber, 100) + "%" };
    },
    verificationProgressWidth() {
      return { width: Math.min(this.verifcationCurrentStepNumber, 100) + "%" };
    }
  },
  created() {}
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
 p {
     margin: 0;
}
 #page {
     font-family: Roboto;
     width: 100%;
     background: #f8f9fa;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}
 .container {
     width: 70%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .progress-bar {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: flex-start;
     width: 100%;
}
 .point {
     width: 38px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     gap: 8px;
     color: #28a745;
}
.step-indicator {
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .not-started {
     background: #ecedee;
     border: none;
}
 .progressing {
     background: #ecedee;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .done {
     background: #28a745;
     border: 4px solid #28a745;
}
 .bar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 16px;
     display: grid;
     align-items: center;
}
 .bar-eform {
     width: 80%;
}
 .bar-verification {
     width: 20%;
}
 .bar-bg {
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #ecedee;
     position: relative;
}
 .bar-arrow {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 4px;
     background-color: #28a745;
}
 .page-indicator {
     color: #28a745;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{{encourageText}}</h3>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="[eFormProgress, 'step-indicator']">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Account</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-eform">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="eformProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="[verificationProgress, 'step-indicator']">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Verification</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bar bar-verification">
        <div class="bar-bg">
          <div class="bar-arrow" v-bind:style="verificationProgressWidth"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="point">
        <div :class="[reviewProgress, 'step-indicator']">
        </div>
        <p><strong>Review</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-indicator">
    <strong>{{currentStepNumber}}/{{totalStepNumber}}</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review. So the CSS, if I use SCSS, it will be simpler?